# Finding largest value in a file and printing out value w name

Tags: python, text-files, return-value, filereader

I need to create a progtam that opens a file then reads the values inside the file and then prints out the name with the largest value.

The file contains the following info:

```
Juan,27
Joe,16 
Mike,29
Roy,10
```

Now the code I have is as follows:

```
UserFile = input('enter file name')
FileOpen = open(User File,'r')
for lines in User File:
    data = line.split(",")
    name = data[0]
    hrs = data[1]
    hrs = int(hrs)
    LHRS = 0
    if hrs > LHRS:
    LHRS = hrs
    if LHRS == LHRS:
        print('Person with largest hours is',name)
```

The following prints out:

```
Person with the largest hours is Juan
Person with the largest hours is Mike
```

How can I make it so it only prints out the true largest?

Comment: You have made some good progress but there are several problems that you need to think about. 1. Fix your indentation in this question. 2. You're resetting `LHRS = 0` for every line in your file, which messes up your algorithm. 3. `LHRS == LHRS` is always going to be true. 4. You need to record the name of the person with the most hours somewhere. 5. You only want to print the person once at the end of your program, but you put that code inside a loop meaning it might happen many times before the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your effort for a first timer is pretty impressive, what you're unable to do here is.. Keep track of the name WHILE keeping track of the max value! I'm sure it can be done in your way, but might I suggest an alternative?

```
import operator
```

Let's read in the file like how I've done. This is good practice, this method handles file closing which can be the cause of many problems if not done properly.

```
with open('/Users/abhishekbabuji/Desktop/example.txt', 'r') as fh:
    lines = fh.readlines()
```

Now that I have each line in a list called `lines`, it also has this annoying `\n` in it. Let's replace that with empty space `''`

```
lines = [line.replace("\n", "") for line in lines]
```

Now we have a list like this. `['Name1, Value1', 'Name2, Value2'..]` What I intend to do now, is for each string item in my list, take the first part in as a key, and the integer portion of the second part as the value to my dictionary called `example_dict`. So in `'Name1, Value1'`, `Name1` is the item in index `0` and `Name2` is my item in index `1` when I turn this into a list like I've done below and added the key, value pair into the dictionary.

```
example_dict = {}
for text in lines:
    example_dict[text.split(",")[0]] = int(text.split(",")[1])
print(example_dict)
```

Gives:

```
{'Juan': 27, 'Joe': 16, 'Mike': 29, 'Roy': 10}
```

Now, obtain the key whose value is max and print it.

```
largest_hour = max(example_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[1]

highest_key = []
for person, hours in example_dict.items():
    if hours == largest_hour:
        highest_key.append((person, hours))

for pair in highest_key:

    print('Person with largest hours is:', pair[0])
```

Comment: This approach is way too high-level for someone learning the basics of coding and algorithms.

Comment: @AlexHall The guy is trying to find the `max` value in a single for loop as he reads line by line.. That's high level for ME! It makes even me pause for a second and think how it works

Comment: @Abhishek question how would I edit the code so it would print out multiple names if they had the same amount of largest hours

Comment: @NathanMndz Check my new edit on the old answer. I just updated it. And if you're happy with it, please upvote and select it as 'Accepted' (Tick mark)

Comment: @NathanMndz You can give it an up vote as well. If you like

Comment: @Abhishek tried but since I have less than 15 rep it won't be displayed :/